# Searching through dates query not working?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, date-format, mysqli

I'm trying to query the recent week rows by using dates. BUT the query is not returning any result. It takes forever to execute.

I checked my DataBase where date is saved in `1446976737` format which seems unix timestamp. BUT in my filters user is entering human readable dates such as `2018-11-11`. Now by executing the below query i'm not getting result. Is there anything wrong with my query?

```
SELECT  `e`.`id` AS `id`, `e`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
        `e`.`gender` AS `gender`,
        `e`.`email` AS `email`, `e`.`phone` AS `phone`, `e`.`age` AS `age`,
        `e`.`version` AS `version`, `e`.`evaluation_status` AS `evaluation_status`,
        `e`.`ip_address` AS `ip_address`, `e`.`date_created` AS `date_created`,
        `e`.`date_updated` AS `date_updated`
    FROM  `evaluation_client` AS `e`
    WHERE
       AND  `e`.`date_created` >= 2018-11-11
       AND  `e`.`date_created` <= 2018-11-18;
```

From the answers and comment i also tried the below query but still it's taking 3 minutes to load the data is it normal? How can i make it faster?

```
SELECT  `e`.`id` AS `id`, `e`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
        `e`.`gender` AS `gender`,
        `e`.`email` AS `email`, `e`.`phone` AS `phone`, `e`.`age` AS `age`,
        `e`.`version` AS `version`, `e`.`evaluation_status` AS `evaluation_status`,
        `e`.`ip_address` AS `ip_address`, `e`.`date_created` AS `date_created`,
        `e`.`date_updated` AS `date_updated`
    FROM  `evaluation_client` AS `e`
    WHERE
        `e`.`date_created` >= unix_timestamp("2015-11-11")
       AND  `e`.`date_created` <= unix_timestamp("2015-11-19")

    ORDER BY
       `e`.`date_created` DESC;
```

Comment: What is the data type of `date_created` ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA `int`

Comment: How many rows in the result?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE evaluation_client` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is why we asked for the datatype of `date_created`!)

**Assuming `date_created` is a `TIMESTAMP`**:

`2018-11-11` is an arithmetic expression that evaluates to `1996`; certainly not what you wanted.

`"2018-11-11"` (with quotes) will compare correctly to 1446976737.

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts_column)` will generate something like `1446976737`, so it should work correctly.  But don't "hide a column in a function".

As for

```
`e`.`date_created` AS `date_created`
```

Since the alias (AS...) does not do anything extra, leave it off.  I am worried that

```
AND  `e`.`date_created`
```

will look at the alias, not the value.  It needs to look at the value to use this:

```
INDEX(date_created)
```

Do you have that index?

By using `>=` and `<=` you are including midnight from both ends; did you intend to do that?

`WHERE AND` is syntactically incorrect.  Did you leave some stuff out?  It may be important.  If you have

```
WHERE x = 1
  AND date_created ...
```

then a better index would be

```
INDEX(x, date_created)
```

`1446976737` dates back a few years:

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1446976737), UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2018-11-11");
+---------------------------+------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1446976737) | UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2018-11-11") |
+---------------------------+------------------------------+
| 2015-11-08 01:58:57       |                   1541923200 |
+---------------------------+------------------------------+
```

When you can't figure out what to do, here's a hint:  See what you get from `SELECT * FROM tbl`.  Then put quotes around something in that format.  In the case of a `TIMESTAMP` column, you will get something like

```
2015-11-08 01:58:57
```

So, you need `date_created = "2015-11-08 01:58:57"`

**Assuming `date_created` is `INT`**:

Either of these is a valid way to compare:

```
date_created >= 1446976737
date_created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-11-08 01:58:57")
```

It is still valid, and wise, to have the index(es) mentioned above.

Comment: I tried all of the above tricks none worked.

I even tried the below

`SELECT 
    `e`.`id` AS `id`,
    `e`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
    `e`.`gender` AS `gender`,
    `e`.`email` AS `email`,
    `e`.`phone` AS `phone`,
    `e`.`age` AS `age`,
    `e`.`version` AS `version`,
    `e`.`evaluation_status` AS `evaluation_status`,
    `e`.`ip_address` AS `ip_address`,
    `e`.`date_created`,
    `e`.`date_updated` AS `date_updated`
FROM
    `evaluation_client` AS `e`
WHERE
    `e`.`date_created` = "1446976737";`

Comment: @DojoDev -  I was wrong.  Just add quotes around `2018-11-11`.  (Fixed my Answer.)

Comment: in table we have entries for dates like `1446976737` which is unix timestamp and datatype for these fields is `int` and I'm comparing input like `2015-11-08` so putting quotes around "2015-11-08" will compare correctly?

Comment: check my updated question please.

Comment: Grrr... I needed to know that it was `INT` instead of `TIMESTAMP`.  See my update.  If there are still issues, please provide a current `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: indexing date_created makes the query a little faster but still in filtering the query takes 3-4 minutes to execute. By filtering i mean when i load the page and then apply another filter so on 2nd time query takes too much time now.

Comment: @DojoDev 3-4 minutes?  Something else needs fixing.  Let's see the things I ask for in my previous Comment.